# How can Alexa get the data from ESP32 directly (Without using intermediate layer like ThingSpeak)?

Tags: esp32, alexa-voice-service

I am currently doing a project in which the Echo/Alexa App should read out the information that is sent by ESP32. Is there a way Alexa can request the data from ESP32? How can that connection between Alexa and ESP32 be established?

I have looked at FauxmoESP. It seems that this library is useful to connect smart lights to Alexa. I created a skill for Alexa. Created a lambda function in AWS. I am stuck with discovering the ESP32 devices in Alexa App and getting the data from ESP32.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old code but with some changes i was able to make it works:
https://github.com/MrBuddyCasino/ESP32_Alexa
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VkszFgxXfg

Also this espressif library is good starting point, but i dont know if amazon is implemented yet:
https://github.com/espressif/esp-adf